# Cassandra Reaper headless service

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

I am preparing to run Cassandra Reaper 3.5.0 against Cassandra 4.1.x as a sidecar in a Kubernetes Pod (in a single Cassandra cluster).

The documentation for Reaper recommends a client-affiliating LoadBalancer service. Is there any reason not to include Reaper ports instead in a headless service, ignoring client awareness of available nodes?